# Playing RTSP videos with h264 output in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, h.264, rtsp, android-video-player

I need to stream RTSP links within a VideoView, and in the case of RTSP links with a .mov output such as *rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov* work fine. However, this one RTSP link I got from someone confidential has a h264 output according to what VLC Player says.
TL;DR how do you implement the streaming of these type of RTSP links and if there's no clear way to code it, are there any external libraries for Android Studio that easily this because I'm kinda at my loss here.

EDIT: Changed title. Streaming can be interpreted differently as in sending RTSP videos from your Android. That's NOT what I want to accomplish. A lot of examples on GitHub are heavily focused on the SD Card Storage and sending it outward, but I am still looking a way to play RTSP videos with h.264 output in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MediaPlayerSDK from VXG. That is the only one that seems to be working and is open source.
https://github.com/VideoExpertsGroup/MediaPlayerSDK

However as per some posts this can be done using libFFMPEG as well. I didnt try it, but you can give it a try.

Comment: How do you add the SDK to your Android Studio project then? It seems like it's not a simple matter of just typing in ".com. [INSERT LINK]" in your gradle.

Comment: What IDE are you using? In case  of eclipse just import SDK as one of projects (make sure "IsLibrary" check box is checked under settings-> Android) and then include that project in settings. For Android Studio in app build.gradle add compile project(':myAndroidSDKName') and it will add and compile it for you.

Comment: So I checked Media Player SDK, and it worked but the problem is that for commercial purposes it needs a rather expensive license -- and well, I'm doing this for a commercial project, so there must be better open source or lesser expensive methods to go by this way.

Comment: You can use onVif to get Camera URL and then play that URL using libFFMPEG. libFFMPEG is open source and free distributed. Most of apps on google play store actually use that only. You may also be able to use curl. I didn't try that/ But here is link: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/rtsp.html